# Attaching debugger with Apache Age - MACOS

Tags: postgresql, debugging, gdb, lldb, apache-age

I'm trying to debug my code on MacOS using a debugger. I attempted to attach gdb debugger, but it didn't work, and running gdb in the terminal returns the following error:

```
syed@syeds-mbp ~ % gdb
zsh: command not found: gdb
```

How can I attach AGE with a debugger like **gdb** for development purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Upon some research I found that Apple switched from **gcc** to **clang** and stopped including **gdb** in MacOS.
The debugger for **clang** is **lldb (Low Level Debugger)** and is available in MacOS.

NOTE: Make sure debugging is enabled in your PostgreSQL configuration and **lldb** flag is set. If not , run the following:

```
./configure --enable-debug --enable-cassert --prefix=$(pwd) CFLAGS="-glldb"
```

**Steps to attach lldb with PostgreSQL processes:**

1. Open a new terminal and type the follwing:

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres | grep -v grep
```

This command filters out the currently running processes and only returns those containing the word "postgres" in them. Copy the **PID** of your postgres process.

2. Running lldb by typing the following in the terminal to launch lldb.

```
lldb
```

3. Attach your postgres process with lldb by running:

```
attach PID      //replace PID with your postgres PID
```

You can now use **lldb** for debugging similar to **gdb**.

Comment: If you are primarily a gdb user new to lldb you might find this page handy: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to install gdb using homebrew:

```
brew install gdb
```

After that run the Apache AGE server using GDB with **debug symbol enabled**.

```
gdb -ex run --args age <AGE_ARGUMENTS>
```

Also, you can use the GDB commands to set breakpoints and inspect through the code.